# How to redirect users to the required html page only after successful login (Flask Python App)?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I am trying to set up login page before accessing any other page. So as of now the code is working fine but if I access '/home' its taking directly to that page without login required page.

I tried to understand online solutions like login-required with SQLAlchemy but nothing seems working and I got totally lost. This does not require login-required I guess.

Here's my code:

```
from dbscriptdeploy import dbupdate
from flask.templating import render_template   
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect

DBupdate = dbupdate() 

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/success')
def deploy_success():
    return render_template("success.html")

def deploy_script(sql):
    res = DBupdate.dbvalues_get(sql)
    return res

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
        error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('form_example'))
return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_example():
    res = None
    error = ''
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            sql = request.form.get('sql')
            res = deploy_script(sql) 
            if res:
                return redirect(url_for('deploy_success'))
            else:
                error = "*Invalid Value. Please try again."

        return render_template('home.html', error=error)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('home.html', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) #run app in debug mode on port 5000
```

Login.html Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Intro - login page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Please login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
          request.form.username }}">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
      request.form.password }}">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  {% if error %}
    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I expect is after successful login only then they should be directed to \home page else they should be directed again to login page.

Comment: I'd advise you to take a look at already made [flask extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) for [authentication](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of building your own: it will both answer your question out of the box and safe tens of hours of development time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However, if you want to develop a simple solution by your own, you should save some var in the user's session.

Also in your login method there is a bug. I'd do:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] == 'admin' and request.form['password'] == 'admin':
            session['admin'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('form_example'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Then, in your `form_example` view you should check that `admin` is in session, else you can redirect to your login view:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_example():
    if 'admin' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    else:
        # Your code here
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down the path of developing your own login/authentication solution, check out the documentation for `flash_message`
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/. This tutorial has the exact problem you're tackling. 
The re-routing of a successful login attempt occurs with the `redirect` call

```
return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
```